# Cannot Open URL, Download Length, and 403 Forbidden Status

Tags: r, url, download, http-status-code-403

I am using the following code in R in an attempt to download a gz file. When entering the URL code through my internet browser I am able to download the file. However, when attempting to use the below code to download the file I get three error messages. 1) Cannot open URL 2) Download length 3) 403 forbidden. Really appreciate all the help!

**CODE:**

```
secweb<-"sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/"
qtrno<-1
crawlme<-paste(secweb,2023, "/QTR", qtrno, "/", "master.gz", sep = "")
directory.path<-"C:/Users/Thomas.Nilson/Desktop/miscellaneos/SEC Downloads"
download.file(crawlme,file.path(directory.path,"master.gz"), mode = "wb", quiet = FALSE)
```

I was expecting the gz file to show up in my working directory and then from there I could use the gunzip function to unzip the file.